# Formatting time in smartGwt using data source

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using **smartGwt6** and TimeItem

```
TimeItem callExpectedAt  = new TimeItem("callExpectedAt", "Expected At");
callExpectedAt.setWidth("*");
callExpectedAt.setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
callExpectedAt.setTimeFormatter(TimeDisplayFormat.TOSHORT24HOURTIME);
```

The format is **appearing correctly in the UI**.

But when I submit the form through my RestDataSource, the value is going as

```
callExpectedAt  04:04:00.000
```

**with second and milliseconds**.

I need to format it to **HH:mm** format.

Comment: can you show the code for retrieving value of `TimeItem` from `RestDataSource`?

Comment: @RAS , I am seeing the value in the http request which is getting triggered(using firebug). If you want to see it in code, you can override the method `protected Object transformRequest(DSRequest dsRequest)` in your data source and you can inspect the attribute of `dsRequest` with the name `callExpectedAt`.

Comment: it seems that you haven't done any coding related to this.. you're suspecting this issue to be present only by inspecting few things in firebug. If you need solution to your problem you need to post the problematic code. Noone is going to do the coding to reproduce the issue for you.

Comment: @RAS ,There is no code written to handle dates manually. Everything is handled by SmartGwt code.
Actually there was an upgrade from smartGwt 3 tosmartGwt 6. In the old version of smartGwt the format is `HH:mm:ss` but after the upgrade it got changed to `HH:mm:ss.SSS`. The new format is not accepted by my rest service provider is not accepting the new format.

Comment: In such a case, you need to raise this issue with SmartGWT developers on this forum: http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a.